# Get specific value (string) in some file that we used to ReadAllText

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Thank you for visiting!! I am a newbie in c# and sorry if I am asking the silly question but I really need to know.

I have this pretending scenario that I want to get some value in some file for example I write the txt file like this:

```
<p>Hello Foo! I am Fityan, How have you been?</p> 
<img src="~/Files/fityan.jpg"/> 
<p>Another tag example<p/>
```

I try to take the `<img/>` tag on the file, so I try to do this:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Files/"+item.Article+".txt");
string imgTag = fileContent.IndexOf("<img").ToString();
```

As you can see, for the result of the code above I got this text:

```
<img src="~/Files/fityan.jpg"/> 
<p>Another tag example<p/>
```

But I want to take only this part:

```
<img src="~/Files/fityan.jpg"/>
```

How can I do that?

I appreciate for the answer, thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I Just found another way to get the html especially image tag in html file. It worked when I try it on my ASP MVC:

```
string imgTagPath = Regex.Match(fileContent, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: You can find index of "/>" or first occurrence of "<p>"in the same way after "<img " and then use substring function of string. In the substring function   you can pass second parameter as difference between two indxes.

Comment: I just realized man wkwkw thanks!!!! It's helpful :D @PratikGaikwad

Comment: Great. If you want I will post an answer some time later as I am traveling now. But I am glad I could help:) and in case I forget I am putting my comments as answer just in case somebody similar to you finds the post. If my comments have helped you please accept it as answer.

Comment: Yeah as you please, Why I didn't think something quite simple like that, oh god XD @PratikGaikwad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more flexibility, or don't like to mess with Regex, try the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It's a great library that will parse the HTML, and then let you examine the HTML using SelectNode.

Answer (score 2):

You can find index of "/>" or first occurrence of "`<p>"` in the same way after `"<img "` and then use **Substring** function of string. In the substring function you can pass second parameter as **difference between two indexes**.